# ajax request on frontend server to api's server was blocked by browser caused different domain (api's server side config is setup properly)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, express, cors

I am developing app as fullstack, with architecture of frontend and backend in separate machine on production. I am using native php as web app server (frontend) and nodejs+expressjs as api server. I set up CORS to give extra security of cookies management on client. It has been tested successfully during development (same machine), but when I tried to test on production env, the request was blocked by client browser. There was no error shown by browser or api's server console (means request hasn't reached api server). But on specific developer based browser, it showed error that request blocked because of different domain. Here's my machine ip config during production test:

1. web app server using ip : http://192.168.1.200:3000 (non https)
2. api server using domain : https://apihost.mycompany.com , with endpoint https://apihost.mycompany.com/auth/info for testing.

I am using nginx as api server engine and proxy_pass to nodejs-express service run on same machine. Maybe this request isn't forwarded to nodejs from nginx.

And here's the code:

```
// WEB APP SERVER - jquery ajax request resides on php page
// // runs on machine http://192.168.1.200:3000
function getUserInfo(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: `https://apihost.mycompany.com/auth/info`,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      // show the page
    },
    error: function(response){
      // show error message here
    },
  });
}
```

```
// API'S SERVER express page on main page with CORS included
// runs on machine https://apihost.mycompany.com
const whiteListOrigin =  ['https://livefrontend.server.com','http://192.168.1.200:3000'];
const whiteListReqMethods = ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'];

var corsOptions = {
  
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whiteListOrigin.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  },
  methods: whiteListReqMethods,
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'x-csrf-token'],
  credentials: true,
  maxAge: 600,
  exposedHeaders: ['*', 'Authorization' ],
  preflightContinue: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204
};

app.options("*", function(req, res, next){
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', "true");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', req.method);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Length, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, csrf-token');
  res.send(200);
});

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

```
// API'S SERVER - controller to send back the respond header
// runs on machine https://apihost.mycompany.com with end point GET-https://apihost.mycompany.com/auth/info
const whiteListOrigin =  ['https://livefrontend.server.com','http://192.168.1.200:3000'];
const allowedOrigin = whiteListOrigin.includes(req.headers.origin)?reqOrigin:whiteListOrigin[0];

const whiteListReqMethods = ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'];
const allowedReqMethod = whiteListReqMethods.includes(req.method)?reqMethod:whiteListReqMethods[0];

res
  .status(statusCode)
  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowedOrigin)
  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", allowedReqMethod)
  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, csrf-token")
  .cookie('token', token, options)
  .json({
    success: true,
    token
  });
```

Error message by Developer's Based Browser:

```
Error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://apihost.mycompany.com/auth/info. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

How can I solve this?

All errors I got on browser:

[image]

Comment: never seen a `CORS request did not success` before ... what exact cors headers are being sent to the client? I don't think you need that `app.options("*", function(req, res, next){` stuff if you're using the `cors` middleware - especially since your code only "allows" the `OPTIONS` method since that's the `req.method` at that time

Comment: @Jaromanda X yes I did see the kind of error you mentioned and many others previously, and I solved it one by one with tons of articles, ask-question page on stackoverflow etc. But this last error I have struggled for 2 days, it's no clue yet. For "what exact cors headers are being sent to the client?" -> No. There's not any response received yet. It hasn't even touch the API server yet, in my opinion reading the error of browser I believe the error still around browser's related (browser blockage).

Comment: `Request Headers : 
-------------------
Accept application: /json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Host: apihost.mycompany.com
Origi: http://192.168.1.200:3000
Referer: http://192.168.1.200:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0`

Comment: I asked for headers sent to the client ... i.e .response headers

Comment: @JaromandaX and I am sorry for the `app.options` about. It was just preflight's things I previously guessed I would had on situation, but actually it was not preflight request tho. And yes There is no any response sent from API SERVER to client (browser) yet.

Comment: of course there is ... you get a CORS error don't you? that's a response

Comment: @JaromandaX please check the screenshot I attached above. Thanks

Comment: The _“CORS request did not succeed”_ message indicates the request failed because the client never successfully connected to the server — and so, never received a response from the server. The most-common cause for it is a failure during SSL negotiation — usually due to some problem with the SSL certificate — that prevents the client from being able to establish at connection to the server. The fact that browsers log it as a CORS error is confusing and misleading — but I guess the reason is that, because the browser gets back no response, it has no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to check.

Comment: Whether or not it is related to SSL, should be verifiable quite easy, if you just call `https://apihost.mycompany.com/auth/info` in your browser directly. Do you get any SSL related errors then?

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks for new insight to call directly the API from browser, it turns out there is SSL problem, since the browser doesn't trust certificate. So after I kept continue to ignore the warning I got new error which is get back the response from API Server as "Not allowed by CORS" (fall back from error caused by origin NOT come from white list origin). After I check the origin's request it is undefined.